# ASP.NET Web API does not receive the data posted from Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to post an angular model to a web API inside .NET Core MVC. The model on the Angular side is populated correctly before the point at which is Posts to the web API. When it reaches the API, however, the model looks like `{"urlEndpoint":null,"token":null}`.

I have tried changing the header `Content-Type`, I have tried adding `[FromBody]`, I have also tried changing the controller from `HttpResponseMessage` to `IHttpActionResult` - pretty much every solution on stack overflow to similar problems actually. However, the interesting thing is, that this same code works in an older project on standard .NET.

Any help with this would be massively appreciated... it's driving me nuts!

Angular component:

```
 getPdfData() {

    let token = this.httpService.getToken("token");

    this.urlAndTokenModel = new UrlAndTokenModel();

    this.urlAndTokenModel.Token = token;
    this.urlAndTokenModel.UrlEndpoint = this.apiEndpoint;
    this.httpService.postPdfBytes('/blahblah/api/pleaseworkthistime', this.urlAndTokenModel, this.successCallback.bind(this),
        this.failureCallback.bind(this));

}
```

Angular http.service

```
    postPdfBytes(url: string, data: UrlAndTokenModel, successCallback, errorCallback) {

    return this.http.post(url, data,
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
            responseType: 'blob'
        }

    ).subscribe(

        resp => successCallback(resp),
        error => errorCallback(error)
        );
}
```

Web API:

```
    public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public TestController(ICacheHelper cacheHelper) : 
        base(cacheHelper)
    {
    }

    [Route("api/pleaseworkthistime")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDocument(UrlAndTokenModel data)
    {

        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", data.Token);

        var responseTask = client.GetAsync(data.UrlEndpoint);

        responseTask.Wait();

        var result = responseTask.Result;

        byte[] finalResult = null;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            readTask.Wait();

            finalResult = readTask.Result;

        }

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(finalResult);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "mytestpdf.pdf";
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return httpResponseMessage;
    }

}
```

Then obviously there is the angular `URLAndTokenModel` with a `URLEndpoint` and a Token - the same is mirrored in the C# model.

Comment: Are you *certain* that the model in your client can be deserialised into your C# model? If not please add them to your question.

Comment: 100% :)  and like I said, I've had the same code working in a different project, which is why this is so confusing.

Comment: and you've configured MVC to use camelCase property names?

Comment: I have indeed :)

Comment: All looks (and sounds) about right then. Could you extract the pertinent bits and post on github?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but the angular url `blahblah/...` does not seems to match with your TestController.

Comment: does sending the same data from Postman or SoupUI work?

Comment: Yeah it work's fine from Postman, Nick (Sorry, should've mentioned that). And it's not the URL gpro, it does actually hit the API, it just doesn't populate the model with any data. 
It's currently within a pretty large project so I'll create a smaller version and get it on github shortly :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! I hope this helps anyone else going through the same issue.

When it posts to the .NET API, it firstly needs to be JSON.Stringify

```
 this.httpService.postPdfBytes('/blahblah/api/pleaseworkthistime', JSON.stringify(this.urlAndTokenModel), this.successCallback.bind(this),
        this.failureCallback.bind(this));
```

The angular http.service also needs to be updated therefore to a string instead of a model.

```
postPdfBytes(url: string, data: string, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

at this point it still wasn't having it, and then a simple add of [FromBody] to the Controller and walahh!

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetDocument([FromBody] UrlAndTokenModel data)
```